# User does not have permission to perform this action. in an image table creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Trying to create an image table I use the following code

```
CMScomClass.SQLComm = New SqlCommand("EXEC sp_configure 'filestream_access_level', '2' ", CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn)
Thread.Sleep(CMScomClass.globalParms.sleepTime)

If CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn.Open()
    CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
Else
    CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If

CMScomClass.SQLComm = New SqlCommand("RECONFIGURE", CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn)
Thread.Sleep(CMScomClass.globalParms.sleepTime)

If CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
     CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn.Open()
     CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
Else
     CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If

CMScomClass.SQLComm = New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE dbo." & tName & " (" &
             FieldName & " UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE , " &
             "Image varbinary(MAX) FILESTREAM NOT NULL ) ", CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn)
Thread.Sleep(CMScomClass.globalParms.sleepTime)

If CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    CMScomClass.globalPar.SQLConn.Open()
    CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
Else
    CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If

CMScomClass.MainWin.OpenCloseImage(sender, e)
```

When my code is before the process of

```
CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I have the following connection string

```
Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MSSQLLocalDB;User ID=CMSadmin;Password=pm@ce#7b$
```

On which we see the user name

```
Uid = CMSadmin password= pm@ce#7b$
```

The user is also 'LoginUser' and database user and has credential to 'sa' account of my server.

The problem is when I’m trying to execute

```
CMScomClass.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

it throws the error

> User does not have permission to perform this action. And also I'm loosing the Password of my account.

The same code was working fine in previous programs now I don’t know why I get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem starts when the Login user is not in the server role and database role

```
sysadmin
```

which he may be added with the database procedure

```
CMScomClass.SQLComm = New SqlCommand("EXEC sp_addrolemember 'sysadmin', '" & User & "'", SQLConn)
             SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and server procedure

```
CMScomClass.SQLComm = New SqlCommand("EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '" & User & "', 'sysadmin'", SQLConn)
               SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```